# Keyboard PCB Design Review Request

Tags: pcb-design, keyboard

I was hoping someone would be able to have a look at a schematic for a split keyboard I've been working on. I know there are quite a few designs online but most of them are using a processor on a breakout board and I would like to have the chip directly on the PCB. I wanted to be sure I have the bypass capacitors done correctly. Any advice would be appreciated.  Thank you

[Hi-Res Schematic](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1CG97dAXzJLhtf-9Wdf6XCJ7fOtDTI8fB/view?usp=sharing)

******************SOLVED FOR NOW******************

I appreciate the help, thank you. That should give me plenty of homework. I will re-post the schematic when I take care of those issues.

******************CAPACITOR SIZING & PLACEMENT******************

I've been looking through the 32u4 datasheet for clarification and they suggested a 10uF capacitor on the VBUS. I believe having extra capacitors would be fine but wanted to check. So far I was planning on the following:

- VBUS [PIN 7 ]: 10uF, 1uF
- VCC  [PIN 14]: 10uF(bulk?), 1uF
- VCC  [PIN 34]: 100nF
- UVCC [PIN 2 ]: 100nF
- AVCC [PIN 24]: 100nF
- AVCC [PIN 44]: 100nF

Comment: It's not public.

Comment: It should be now.

Answer (score 1):

> *Any advice would be appreciated*

- I don't see any pull down resistors on the rows - maybe they are internal and set-up in your code.
- I don't see pin numbers on devices - this makes it hard to check things.
- You don't have notes on the circuit that tells prospective layout guys (if used) how to position the decoupler capacitors.
- I'd consider putting power reverse protection on the incoming power supply on J1. It looks like it may be a USB connector so I'd also be concerned about adding TVS diodes to protect from ESD event surges.

Comment: It's a ATmega32u4-au from what I understand it has internal resistors, but I will definitely check into it. (sorry for the lack of details. It's my first attempt at electronics) Thank you

Comment: When it comes to the decoupler capacitors; for each voltage input there is a corresponding ground pin on the chip. If I understand correctly the capacitors should be connected between these pins (VCC -> GND, UVCC -> GND...) as close to the chip as possible. Is this correct?

Comment: You should use a capacitor for each power pin and connect that capacitor to ground via the ground/earth/0 volts plane - they should be sited close to voltage supply pins and not close to grounding pins. As close to the chip as possible, yes.

Answer (score 0):

- What value is R1/R2?
- You should be including TVS diodes on the USB lines
- Are all the caps after the USB connector for decoupling? Which line do they belong to?
- You should probably include some bulk capacitance
- I believe you need resistors for the LED's to limit current there
- Is J1 a USB port? Why is it labeled an ICSP part? Check that you have the right part there. If it is an ICSP, it should not have D+/D-...

Comment: R1/R2 are 22.6ohm (I was trying to clean up the schematic and removed useful information.)

Comment: J1 would be where the USB cable connects, I just want to have the cable soldered to the board using pads or thru-holes but wasn't sure what to add for a component. I used the same component on the I2C connection as placeholders until I find the correct component.